# JavaScript Client object model, rename folder

Tags: document-library, javascript, client-object-model, front-end

I am trying to rename a folder inside a Document library. Right now I get my item and everything is good but when I try to rename it using `set_item('title', 'NewFolderName')` it crashes and unwinds the stack.

Is there some kind of documentation that would help us with that? Should I be doing this on the backend instead of the frontend?

*Working*

```
context = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
var iter = folderList.getEnumerator();
iter.moveNext();

var folder = iter.get_current();

folder.set_item('Title', 'TestTitleRename');
folder.set_item('FileLeafRef', 'TestTitleRename');
folder.update();
context.executeQueryAsync(Success,Failure);
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you not only set the "Title" but also the "FileLeafRef" (to the same value as the Title)?

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting? Can you post your code here? See the following link on updating a listitem. (The folder is also a list item ultimately) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185011.aspx

Comment: Yes i was missing FileLeafRef, post as answer and ill mark yours. Thanks :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I commented already: ;-)

You have to set not only the "Title" but also the "FileLeafRef".